# React Admin - CloneButton - exclude id

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have used the 'clonebutton' from react-admin which will allow me to clone/copy the existing data record into another one and will open the edit form. But It clone all fields , i just want to exclude the id field else i've got an error :

```
{"name":"Conflict","message":"id: value already exists.","code":409,"className":"conflict","errors":{"id":"value"}}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: In https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button/CloneButton.tsx
I can see source: JSON.stringify(omitId(record)), and omitId exclude only id but in mongoose the identifier is _id , any idea to bypass ?

Comment: The only solution i have found : 

    const CloneElement = ({ record }) => {
    return record ? (
        <CloneButton
            to={{
                pathname: '/templates/create',
                search: `?source=${JSON.stringify(omitId(record))}`,
            }}
        />
    ) : null;
    };
    const omitId = ({ _id, ...rest }) => rest;

Comment: const TemplateList = (props) => {
      return (
        <List {...props}>
          <Datagrid rowClick='edit'>
            <TextField source='templateName' />
            <TextField source='subject' />
            <TextField source='htmlContent' />
            <TextField source='lang' />
            <CloneElement />
          </Datagrid>
        </List>
      );
    };